# R: Apply.yearly sums from Jan non inclusive to Jan in the following year inclusive. How could I make it sum from Dec to Dec?

Tags: r, xts

In R, the below code:

```
apply.yearly(XTS_object, sum)
```

returns the sums from Jan in the first year non inclusive to Jan in the following year inclusive.

How could I make it sum from December to December?

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output based on that.

Comment: Do a search on 'seasonal' or 'financial year'. There are already a couple of answers for shifting the divisions of Dates to use as index arguments. You will also need to look at the code for `apply.yearly`. Very simple once you have the two pieces .... if you are a "coding enthusiast" as we all are, right?

Answer (score 0):

Extract `endpoints` and use with `period.apply`:

```
getSymbols("SPY", from = "2013-12-01")
# Use your own data. Assuming Data already starts from December, otherwise extract all months and get Decembers only:
december <- endpoints(SPY, k = 12)
[1]   0 251 503

SPY[251 + 1]
               SPY.Open   SPY.High    SPY.Low  SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
    2014-12-01 206.399994 206.539993 205.380005 205.759995  103968400   199.464546

period.apply(Ad(SPY), december + 1, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks, are there no pre-built parameters in any functions that would do the same?

Comment: The problem with period.apply is that is it loses the xts object format. It really is not ideal. isn't there anything else out there?
Also, why isnt anyone complaining about this bug in apply.yearly?

Comment: I am not really sure, why you think it is a bug. Maybe, I am misunderstanding you. Please provide reproducible example.